# $(a,b,c) \cdot (f_x, f_y, -1) = 0$, is the vector $(a,b,c)$ also in the plane tangent to the surface $z = f(x,y)$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a surface $z = f(x,y)$, then we know at a particular point its normal vector is $(f_x, f_y, -1)$.

Suppose further that I have a vector $(a, b, c)$, where $a,b$, and $c$ are themselves functions of $x$ and $y$, and that
$$(a,b,c) \cdot (f_x, f_y, -1) = 0$$
By definition then the vector $(a,b,c)$ is orthogonal to the normal vector $(f_x, f_y, -1)$. I am following a set of notes which then claims that because of the above dot product, we can conclude that $(a,b,c)$ must lie in the tangent plane to the surface $z$, but I cannot see why or how this holds. What prevents the vector $(a,b,c)$ from being parallel to the surface $z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are thinking of these vectors not as starting at the origin but as starting from an arbitrary base point in $\mathbb R^3$. In this particular case, the base point is taken to be some point on the surface $z=f(x,y)$. Hence, the dot product condition implies $(a,b,c)$, thought of as a vector coming out of some point on the surface, is orthogonal to the normal to the surface at that point. This implies that $(a,b,c)$ is in the tangent plane of the surface pretty much by definition.